# How get installation path in pkg during installation stage

Tags: macos, pkg-file

The procedure is like this:

a).I have a pkg package named for example:  abc.pkg.

b).There is a script named preinstall inside abc.pkg. This script is one of the step run during abc.pkg installation stage.

c).The PackageInfo of this abc.pkg file is:

```
   <pkg-info
      .....
   <relocate>
      <bundle id="xxxx"/>
   </relocate>
   <scripts>
      <preinstall file="**./preinstall**"/>
   </scripts>
   </pkg-info>
```

d).The preinstall is a script which will write something with installation path. So I need pass the installation path(This path is the destination path used selected in UI)to this script

e).The user will double click the abc.pkg file to begin installation.

So my question is:

a).How I can get known the "destination path" during the installation runtime and how pass to my script?

b).My abc.pkg always install to the /Applications. I do not know why it always install to this path?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Perhaps you should try to outline the procedure you're following in more detail.

Comment: I've updated the description, hope clear.